# Creating multiple modeless dialogs from one parent dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a UI program in C# WPF .NET3.5. In my main window, I have a button. When the user clicks on this button it creates a modeless dialog. Changing the focus back to main window and clicking the button again creates another modeless dialog. The sequence of dialogs is as below:

M -> C1 -> C2 -> C3

where M is the main window, C1, C2 and C3 are child windows in the order. C1 is modeless (created using Window.Show() method with Owner property not set) and C2 and C3 are modal (created using Window.ShowDialog() method with Owner property set). What I expect is that user should be able to create multiple C1, C2 and C3 dialogs from M.

My problem is as follows. If I create 2 C1 dialogs, everything works fine. I can perform all UI operations in M and the two C1 dialogs. However, once C2 and C3 dialogs are created from one C1 dialog, I cannot perform any UI operations in another C1 dialog and M dialog. I can however perform UI operations in C3 dialog.

C2 dialog contains a progress bar which is updated using DispatcherTimer. After the operations in progress are completed, C3 dialog is launched from event handler of DispatcherTimer.

I thank you in advance for your valuable support.

Comment: See the definition of Windows.ShowDialog()  "Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed."

Comment: Yes. ShowDialog() blocks the calling function. That would block event handler of C1. But it would not block any event handlers of M. Still I cannot perform any UI operations in M. Anyway, this might be the default behavior. The answer from Jon below gives explanation to what is causing the problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: But according to your question it is blocking M.  Where does it say "blocks the calling"?  It says "returns only".

Comment: I apologize if my explanation was not clear. In M, button click event handler calls C1.Show() which returns immediately. This event handler is not blocked till C1 closes. But if C2 and C3 are opened, no UI operations can be performed in M. The documentation does not say "blocks the calling". But parent function calling ShowDialog() would block till ShowDialog() returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find another way to set C2 and C3 to be always on top, outside of using modal dialogs.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> A modal form or dialog box must be closed or hidden before you can
>   continue working with the rest of the application.

Try setting the [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx) property of C2 and C3 to true and use `Window.Show()` instead of `Window.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I now know why I cannot perform UI operations on all dialogs except C3. I will make C2 and C3 modeless and use a different method to bring one dialog on top of another. I will let you know how it works.

Comment: Making window topmost would bring it on top of all other windows. I need a slightly different design. Let us say user opens M, 2 C1 dialogs and one C2 and one C3 dialog from one of the C1 dialogs. When user clicks the parent C1 dialog, C3 should be shown on top. If user clicks on M, M should be shown on top. If user clicks other C1 dialog, that dialog should be shown on top. Is there an event that gets generated when user selects a window, i.e. brings the window to top? With this event I can bring appropriate window to top using Activate() function.